# Сколько способов представить положительное число в виде суммы нечетных слагаемых?

Tags: c++

Задано целое положительное число n. Требуется найти число способов
представить его в виде суммы нечетных слагаемых. При этом разбиения,
отличающиеся только порядком слагаемых, считаются одинаковыми.
Сказали решать "методом динамического программирования",  уже который час сижу, не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста, можно просто алгоритм, или какие-то пояснения.
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Почитайте [это][1]


  [1]: http://www.fvn2009.narod.ru/Olympiads/Rules_Olympiads/Rules24.htm

Comment: @akisha это, правда не совсем C++, но. Если слагаемые не могут быть одинаковыми, то

      f n = filter (/=[]) $ f' [] 0 [1,3..] where 
      f' s sumS (l:ls) | sumS + l == n = [reverse $ l:s]
                       | sumS + l > n  = [[]]
                       | otherwise     = f' (l:s) (sumS+l) ls ++ f' s sumS ls

Если могут, то f' меняется на

      f' s sumS (l:ls) | sumS + l == n = [reverse $ l:s]
                       | sumS + l > n  = [[]]
                       | otherwise     = f' (l:s) (sumS+l) (l:ls) ++ f' s sumS 

Но в этом случае первым будет список из одних единиц

Comment: @alexlz, нужно просто найти число способов, без их генерации и вывода на экран

Comment: @akisha

    f n = length $ filter (/=[]) $ f' [] 0 [1,3..] where

и далее по тексту. А вообще не совсем понятно, каким боком тут динамическое программирование. Обычный поиск с возвращением. Ну а если надо аналитически вывести зависимость результата от числа n -- так это совсем другая дисциплина.

Comment: Снова замерло всё до рассвета...

    #include <iostream>
    int akisha(int n, int sumS, int oddNumber) {
      if(sumS + oddNumber == n) return 1;
      if(sumS + oddNumber > n) return 0;
      return akisha(n, sumS+oddNumber, oddNumber + 2) + akisha(n, sumS, oddNumber + 2);
    }
    int main() {
      int n;
      std::cin >> n;
      std::cout << akisha (n, 0, 1) << std::endl;
    }

Вариант hs

    f n = f' 0 1 where 
      f' sumS oddN | sumS + oddN == n = 1
                   | sumS + oddN > n  = 0
                   | otherwise = f' (sumS+oddN) o + f' sumS o where o = oddN + 2

Comment: @alexlz, реализация классная, но не генерирует варианты, в которых есть совпадающие слагаемые, в частности, все единицы. Например, для числа 6 найдет только один вариант (1,5), не найдет (1,1,1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,3), (3,3). Предлагаю так:

        return akisha(n, sumS+oddNumber, oddNumber) + akisha(n, sumS+oddNumber, oddNumber + 2) + akisha(n, sumS, oddNumber + 2);

Comment: @paulgri лень смотреть, но кажется, что сосчитаете дубликаты. По-моему д.быть

     return akisha(n, sumS+oddNumber, oddNumber) + akisha(n, sumS, oddNumber + 2);

(См. примеры на haskell)

Comment: @alexlz, да, наверное так )). Не могу сейчас посмотреть, только планшет под рукой.

Answer (score 1):

```
int counts(int N, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    if (M == INT_MAX) M = N;
    if (N <= 1 || M == 1) return 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N && i <= M; i+=2)
    {
        sum += counts(N - i, i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Кстати, см. https://oeis.org/A000009